# modx revo formit hook not working

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution, formit

I'm using MODX 2.4.2 and I have a multi-page FormIt-form. In this form the user has the possibility to choose from different radio-boxes. Depending on the choice the user made the selection gets valued. Those values need to get calculated/summated together, to receive a total value, which will be used for further calculating.

So far I have a snippet/hook "**calculating**" like this:

```
<?php

$age = $hook->getValue('age');

if($age === '40') { $result = '111'; } 
if($age === '50') { $result = '222'; } 

if($married === 'yes') { $result = $result + '333'; } 
if($married === 'no') { $result = $result + '444'; } 

$hook->setValue('all', $result);
return true;
```

The hook gets called in the FormIt-snippet-call (having a typo in it leads the form to an error, so the hooks implemented).

```
[[!FormIt? 
&hooks=`spam,calculating,email,redirect` 
&redirectTo=`36` 
&validate=`age:required, married:required,` 
&emailTpl=`Step1` 
&emailTo=`info@abc.de` 
&emailSubject=`new message` 
&store=`1`
]]
```

So imagine the user did choose the age "40" and that he is married. This should result in 111 + 333 = 444, but I'm just getting the placeholder **[[+all]]** displayed in the email i'm getting sent via FormIt.

Even without the calcultion part I'm just getting the blank placeholder **[[+all]]**:

```
<?php

$age = $hook->getValue('age');

if($age === '40') { $result = '111'; } 
if($age === '50') { $result = '222'; } 

$hook->setValue('all', $result);
return true;
```

What is going wrong here, any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: adding some form-code:

```
<form action="[[~[[*id]]]]" method="post" class="form">
<input type="hidden" name="nospam:blank" value="[[+fi.nospam]]" />

<span>1. Age</span><br /> 

<input type="radio" name="age[]" value="40" [[!+fi.age:FormItIsChecked=`40`]]" />> 40 years
<input type="radio" name="age[]" value="50" [[!+fi.age:FormItIsChecked=`50`]]" />> 50 years
<input type="radio" name="age[]" value="60" [[!+fi.age:FormItIsChecked=`60`]]" />> 60 years
<input type="radio" name="age[]" value="70" [[!+fi.age:FormItIsChecked=`70`]]" />> 70 years
<input type="radio" name="age[]" value="80" [[!+fi.age:FormItIsChecked=`80`]]" />> 80 years

<br /><br />

<span>2. Married</span><br /> 

<input type="radio" name="married[]" value="yes" [[!+fi.married:FormItIsChecked=`yes`]]" />yes
<input type="radio" name="married[]" value="no" [[!+fi.married:FormItIsChecked=`50no]]" />no

<br /> <br /> 

<input class="button" type="submit" value="Weiter" />
</form>
```

Comment: Could you add the form code please.

Answer (score 0):

$result is undefined if the tests are not successful, so the placeholder won't be replaced in that case. Init it with an empty value to avoid this.

Please check, what's in **$age**, it is an array because you have used **name="age[]"**

BTW: $married has never a value in your code.

Comment: Thx Jako for your answer! By adding "$result = "";" on line 4 I don't get the "pure" placeholder ([[+all]]), instead I'm getting a blank-placeholder containing nothing.
I also checked the $age, but it definately contains a single string/number, it's not an array.
The "married"-part I added for showing what I wanted to achieve, didn't test this before, but you're right...

Comment: I did a little progress by changing the **name="age[]"** to **name="age"**...now the first variables are read and calculated...but now I have an array **children[]**, several checkboxes have been checked and the array as different values; now I'm trying to get every single selection and give each one a unique value...

Comment: You could use $children = $hook->getValue('children'); and do a foreach on $children in that case.